# How To Post Json Data To Controller Without a Model in .net core

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, .net-core

There is a huge data stored in grid that comes from a sql query joined more than ona table. Data type is Json. I filtered data and then want to sent filtered data to controller. But how it can be?
Here is test json data in javascript block:

```
var jsonData = {
    "FirstName": "John",
    "LastName": "Doe",
    "DoB": "01/01/1970" };
```

And this is my javascript function:

```
function submitForm() {
    var user = jsonData;

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("GetJsonData", "Account")",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(user),
        success: function (data) { alert(data); },
        failure: function (errMsg) {
            alert(errMsg);
        }
    });
}
```

How to get the Json data in controller? Here is my [HttpPost] method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult GetJsonData(String user)
    {
        //...
        return null;
    }
```

user gets null.. Should i change type "`String`" in method or something else?

Comment: is this JavaScript inside a Razor view? It needs to be, otherwise the `@Url.Action` won't work.

Comment: No, it's not about Razor View. Because i point a breakpoint for `GetJsonData` method, and the method works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `user` is a string, you could try to create an object with a property `user`:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "@Url.Action("GetJsonData", "Account")",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: { 
        user: JSON.stringify(user) 
    },
    success: function (data) { alert(data); },
    failure: function (errMsg) {
        alert(errMsg);
    }
});
```

---

Or using `FormData`:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('user', JSON.stringify(user));

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "@Url.Action("GetJsonData", "Account")",
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: formData,
    success: function (data) { alert(data); },
    failure: function (errMsg) {
        alert(errMsg);
    }
});
```

Comment: I created an object with a property `user` but it still returns null...

Comment: @sudu That's because of `return null;` in the method `GetJsonData`.

Comment: No, i mean `GetJsonData` parameter's `user` returns `null`

Comment: And if i use formData javascript notify me : _"Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation"_

Comment: @sudu Oh, sorry. I've updated the second way, you can try again. I've removed `dataType` property, and added 2 properties `contentType` and `processData`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tân Nguyễn, updated way solved my proplem :)

Comment: If you want to use JSON, you might need to add FromBody to the controller method: `public IActionResult GetJsonData([FromBody] String user)`